# cambiar zona horaria en apache tomcat

Tags: java, apache, tomcat

Tengo una maquina virtual instalada con windows 7 y quiero cambiarle la zona horaria debido a que como soy de colombia cuando intento de ingresar una hora por un aplicativo llamado `open data kit` me la cambia 5 horas adelantas, ej: si yo ingrese como hora las 10 am, en la base de datos de `open data kit` me guarda las 15:00 o sea las 3 de la tarde, busque por paginas en ingles y dicen que hay que configurar la zona horaria en el archivo `setenv.bat` en la carpeta `bin` y esta es el codigo que tengo en el archivo `set JAVA_OPTS="-Duser.timezone=GMT–05:00"` y no está funcionando.

Comment: Hola, el archivo se debe llamar "setenv.sh"

Comment: segun tengo entendido setenv.sh no es para linux??

Comment: Perdo, quise decir setenv.bat, tu archivo .bat se llama diferente

Comment: en eso yo tambien me perdono mi archivo si se llama setenv.bat si no q cuando empece a escribir fue mi error de digitacion pero en verdad se llama asi

Answer (score 0):

Ingresa a

```
Inicio > Configure Tomcat > JAVA > JAVA options
```

Y agrega `-Duser.language=en -Duser.region=US` (ingresa el lenguaje y región deseado)